# Enable numlock at login screen - with thin client?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, numlock, xdmcp

I want to enable numlock at the login screen. `numlockx` is already installed. I've tried adding `greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on` to `etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, which by the way only works if it's in the `[SeatDefaults]` section (there appears to be an `[XDMCPServer]` section as well).

But then, numlock *only* works for the main computer while my thin client blacks out (no login screen or any screen at all). What's wrong?

Here's my `etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu

[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
port=177
```

My thin client is an Ncomputing L300 with vSpace Server 3.2.2.8, running on Ubuntu 12.04.04. I cannot upgrade to 14.04 because the vSpace software doesn't support that yet.

Thanks for helping me out.